# Type Mismatch when I delete values from cells

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am pretty new to VBA and am running into a very frustrating error. My code attempts to lock and black out cells based on the values of other cells. However, if any cell in the worksheet is deleted, the code breaks and I get a type mismatch error. The code does not break if the value of a cell is changed, only if it is deleted.

My code is provided below, does anybody have ideas? Thanks in advance!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target <> Range("$C$28") And Target <> Range("$C$31") Then Exit Sub

  ActiveSheet.Unprotect

  If Range("C31") = "Cellular" And Range("C28") = "No" Then
    Range("C34").Locked = False
    Range("C34").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C35").Locked = True
    Range("C35").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C35").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C37").Locked = False
    Range("C37").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C38").Locked = False
    Range("C38").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

  ElseIf Range("C31") = "Cellular" And Range("C28") = "Yes" Then
    Range("C34").Locked = False
    Range("C34").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C35").Locked = True
    Range("C35").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C35").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C37").Locked = True
    Range("C37").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C37").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C38").Locked = True
    Range("C38").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C38").Value = "Verizon"

  ElseIf Range("C31") <> "Cellular" And Range("C28") = "No" Then
    Range("C34").Locked = True
    Range("C34").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C34").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C35").Locked = False
    Range("C35").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C37").Locked = False
    Range("C37").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C38").Locked = False
    Range("C38").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

  Else
    Range("C34").Locked = True
    Range("C34").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C34").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C35").Locked = False
    Range("C35").Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Range("C37").Locked = True
    Range("C37").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C37").Value = "Verizon"
    Range("C38").Locked = True
    Range("C38").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    Range("C38").Value = "Verizon"

 End If

 ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: I only get 'type mismatch' when I delete a whole row. Is this what you are experiencing? And does the error occur on the first line of the proc?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an entire row, you should confirm that the resulting `Target` object will represent an entire row range.  So your comparison statement will fail, because you're relying on the implicit/default property of a range object (its `.Value` property).  A multi-cell range will raise an error when attempting to reference this property, in this manner.

So you need some logic to avoid this. Perhaps something as simple as examining the first cell in the `Target` range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells(1,1) <> Range("$C$28") And Target <> Range("$C$31") Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, David. However, this did not fix the problem. It is not necessarily entire rows. If I delete the contents of any cell in the worksheet, this problem occurs.

Comment: Again I would ask first that you confirm the `Target.Address` by debugging your code.  Ensure that what you *think* is the target actually *is* the target.  Additional things to consider: What is in `C28`? If it is a formula, the deletion may impact the formula's calculation such that it results in an error value like `=N/A!` or `=REF!` or `=DIV0/!`, etc.; these sometimes make problems.